# Ícone na parte superior de uma janela

Tags: tkinter

Preciso altera o ícone no canto esquerdo de uma janela que criei, o código que tenho como exemplo é o seguinte, mas não funciona:

```
objeto.tk.call("icone.ico");
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar o método `iconbitmap`

```
import Tkinter

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.iconbitmap('CAMINHO_COMPLETO_PARA_O_ICON/ICON.ICO')
window.mainloop()
```

#### Referência

- [Tkinter.Tk.iconbitmap](https://kite.com/docs/python;Tkinter.Tk.iconbitmap)